# Convert a list of IDs into a list of objects with an ORM like Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, orm, collections

In web applications it is common to send a list of IDs to the server when selecting elements of a collection. There could be a HTML form representing a course and it would contain a list with all students of a semester. By selecting some students they would be associated with the course. The server would receive a list of student IDs.

What is the best practise to convert this list of IDs (primary keys in the DB) into a list of domain objects with an ORM like Hibernate? I'd like to avoid to write the same code for each domain class again. [Grails](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.1.6%20Data%20Binding) does something like that (but I don't know how).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so we have a generic DAO with a method like this

```
public <T extends IDomainObject> List<T> getAll(Class<T> type, List<Integer> ids) {
    return (List<T>) session.createCriteria(type).add(Restrictions.in("id", ids).list();
}
```

By convention all our domain model objects implements `IDomainObject` and have a primary key field named `id`.